# On the fixed point of automorphism of $\mathbb F_3[[T]]$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, automorphism-groups

Consider the automorphism $\sigma$ on ${\Bbb F}_3[[T]]$ such that $T \mapsto c_1T + f(T)$ with $c_1 = 1$ or $-1$, and $f(T) \not=0$ and the non-zero leading term $c_mT^m$ of $f(T)$ satisfies $m \geq 2$.

Question: Is there any fixed element $t \in {\Bbb F}_3[[T]]$ other than those in the constant field ${\Bbb F}_3$? Namely does such $t$ exist as $\sigma(t) = t$ 
but $t \notin {\Bbb F}_3$?

Pierre

Answer (score 4):

Let's write $R$ for $\mathbb{F}_3[[T]]$ and $K$ for its fraction field. Suppose $t \in R \setminus \mathbb{F}_3$ satisfies $\sigma(t)=t$. I claim that $\sigma$ then has finite order.

Suppose first that the valuation $k$ of $t$ is coprime to $3$. Then I claim that the order of $\sigma$ divides $k$. Indeed, there exists (**after possibly taking a base extension of the ground field $\mathbb{F}_3$, as Michael Zieve pointed out in a comment**) an automorphism $\alpha$ of $R$ that maps $t$ to $T^k$. So then $\alpha(\sigma(\alpha^{-1}(T)))=\zeta T$ for some $k$-th root of unity $\zeta$, hence $\sigma$ has order dividing $k$.

Now the general case. I am a bit uncertain about this, since it almost seems too easy, but here goes. I first want to prove that if $K_0$ is the topological closure of $\mathbb{F}_3(t)$ in $K$, then $K$ is of finite degree over $K_0$. Now $K_0$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_3((t))$, hence is a locally compact normed field with respect to the absolute value induced by that on $K$. Furthermore, the field $K=\mathbb{F}_3((T))$ is a locally compact normed $K_0$-vector space, so by e.g. Lemma 2 in [these notes by Pete Clark](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/8410Chapter5.pdf)) we conclude that $K$ has finite dimension over $K_0$. But then $\sigma$ extended to $K$ is an element of the finite group $\operatorname{Aut}(K/K_0)$. Therefore $\sigma$ has finite order as an automorphism of $K$, and therefore also as an automorphism of $R$.

Conversely, if $\sigma$ has finite order $k$, then symmetric expressions in $T$, $\sigma(T)$, $\ldots$, $\sigma^{(k-1)}(T)$ should give plenty of power series on which $\sigma$ acts trivially. (This has been worked out much better in Michael's answer and the comments below it.)

Comment: Jonathan Lubin's "Torsion in the Nottingham group" discusses the structure of finite order $\sigma$.

Comment: Rene, I am satisfied and thank for Michael and Rene. Pierre

Comment: Nice proof!  So the conclusion is that $\sigma$ has a fixed point if and only if it has finite order.  As I mentioned, the finite-order elements with $\sigma'(T)=1$ have been studied quite a bit; and of course, a finite-order element with $\sigma'(T)=-1$ satisfies $(\sigma^2)'(T)=1$.

Comment: By the way, part (1) of my answer shows that the hypotheses of the first part of your answer actually imply that $\sigma$ has order dividing $2$.

Comment: Since this question was just bumped, I want to point out that your too easy proof was in fact not easy enough. Say $t = a_m T^m+$ higher order terms. Then $\mathbb F_3((T))$ has dimension (at most) $m$ over $\mathbb F_3((t))$, and in fact $1, T, \dots, T^{m-1}$ form a basis, since using them and a suitable power of $t$ we can cancel the leading term of any power series, and then the next one, and the next one, and so on.

Comment: @WillSawin Well at least I sensed that something was off about the proof. Thank you Will, I appreciate this.

Answer (score 3):

I show here: (1) if $c_1=1$ and $\sigma$ is not the identity then $\sigma$ has no fixed points whose lowest-degree nonconstant term has degree coprime to $3$; and (2) if $\sigma$ has finite order under composition, then $\sigma$ has fixed points outside $\mathbf{F}_3$.

To prove (1), let $t\in\mathbf{F}_3[[T]]$ be fixed by $\sigma$, and assume that the lowest degree of any nonconstant term of $t$ is some integer $n$ which is coprime to $3$. By definition, $\sigma(t)=t(T+f(T))$, where $f(T)\in\mathbf{F}_3[[T]]$ and the lowest degree of any term of $f(T)$ is some integer $m>1$.  By replacing $t$ by $t-t(0)$, we may assume that $t(0)=0$; this does not affect the other hypotheses on $t$.  Joe Silverman's argument handles the case $n=1$:  there is some $s\in\mathbf{F}_3[[T]]$ such that $s(t)=T$, so if
$t=\sigma(t)=t(T+f(T))$ then by applying $s$ to both sides we obtain the contradiction $T=T+f(T)$.  If $n>1$ then use Taylor expansion to compute
$$
\sigma(t)=t(T+f(T))=t+f(T)t'+\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} f(T)^i H^{(i)}(t),
$$
where $H^{(i)}(t)$ is the $i$-th Hasse derivative of $t$, defined by $H^{(i)}(\sum c_k T^k)=\sum c_k\binom{k}{i}T^{k-i}$.  But each term in the summation has degree at least $mi+n-i$, which is at least $m+n$ since $m\ge 2$.  Since the lowest-degree term of $f(T)t'$ has degree $m+n-1$, it follows that $\sigma(t)-t$ has a term of degree $m+n-1$ and hence $\sigma(t)\ne t$.

Item (2) was mostly shown in a (since-deleted) answer by user René, who observed that if $\sigma$ has finite order (say $n$), then it fixes every symmetric polynomial in $T, \sigma(T), \sigma^2(T), \dots, \sigma^{n-1}(T)$.  This proves (2) because the values of these symmetric polynomials can't all be in $\mathbf{F}_3$; this can be shown in various ways, for instance Yves Cornulier notes that the product of the $\sigma^i(T)$'s has a degree-$n$ term.

Finally, I note that there has been a good deal of work studying power series in $\mathcal{N}:=X+X^2\mathbf{F}_p[[X]]$ which have finite order under composition.  It isn't hard to show that any such element has order $p^r$ for some $r$.  Klopsch explicitly determined the elements of order $p$, up to conjugacy by an element of $\mathcal{N}$: they are $X(1-inX^n)^{-1/n}$ where $i\in\mathbf{F}_p^*$ and $n$ is a positive integer coprime to $p$.  The conjugacy classes of elements of order $p^r$ were described in terms of Artin-Schreier-Witt theory in Jean's thesis.  Alternate proofs and further developments are in Lubin's paper cited below.  Still, the problem of explicitly describing an element of order $p^r$ remains open in all cases except $r\le 1$ and $p=r=2$.  In case $p=r=2$ the element was constructed by Chinburg and Symonds; subsequently, together with Bleher and Poonen, they showed that their approach could not be generalized to other cases.  References are below.

Benjamin Klopsch, Automorphisms of the Nottingham group, Journal of Algebra 223 (2000), 37-56

Sandrine Jean, Conjugacy classes of series in positive characteristic and Witt vectors, Journal de Théorie des Nombres Bordeaux 21 (2009), 263-284

Jonathan Lubin, Torsion in the Nottingham group, Bulletin of the London Mathematical Society 43 (2011), 547-560.

Ted Chinburg and Peter Symonds, An element of order 4 in the Nottingham group at the prime 2, arXiv:1009.5135.

Frauke Bleher, Ted Chinburg, Bjorn Poonen and Peter Symonds, Automorphisms of Katz-Gabber covers, [preprint available online](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~pas/preprints/kg.pdf).

Comment: Your argument for finite order can be simplified: the symmetric polynomial can just be chosen to be the product $X_1X_2\dots X_n$, since it is an element of valuation $n$, it is not a constant. In other words, if $\sigma$ has order $n$ then it fixes the nonconstant element $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\sigma^i(T)$.

Comment: @Yves: nice!  That's much nicer than my argument, so I edited it into my answer.

Comment: Mike, I thought that the Chinburg-Symonds example ($p=r=2$) was just a really nice formal expansion of the $i$-automorphism of a supersingular elliptic curve over $\mathbb F_2$ whose endomorphism ring over that field is $\mathbb Z[i]$.

Comment: Jonathan, yes that's correct, but that isn't the potential generalization they studied (and showed didn't exist) in the paper with Bleher and Poonen.

Answer (score 2):

The elements in $\mathbb{F}_p[[T]]$ of the form $T+T^2f(T)$ form a group under composition, the Nottingham group $\mathcal{N}_p$. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nottingham_group.) So in the case that $c_1=1$, your $\sigma$ is in $\mathcal{N}_p$, and you're asking if there is some $\tau\in\mathcal{N}_p$ such that $\sigma\star\tau=\tau$. (Here I write $\star$ for the group law, which is composition.) Since $\mathcal{N}_p$ is a group, I can multiply (compose) on the right by $\tau^{-1}$ to conclude that $\sigma(T)=T$. Hmmm... Okay, so I guess this means that your $t$ needs to have a constant term, and also I guess you've assumed that your $f(T)$ is a polynomial, otherwise you can't evaluate $f(t)$ when $t$ is a power series. So this doesn't completely solve your problem, but it at least eliminates all $t$'s that don't have a constant term.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, what this argument eliminates is $t$'s of the form $T+T^2g(T)$. (And probably $cT+T^2g(T)$ with $c\ne0$). There remains the interesting question of $t$'s that start with a $T^2$ or higher terms. So my answer is merely a possible start, and also a suggestion that the literature on the Nottingham group might be relevant. The thesis of Matthew Gradner-Spencer might also be relevant:
https://repository.library.brown.edu/studio/item/bdr:11323/  He looks at various actions of the Nottingham group on power series starting $T^p+h.o.t.$.

Comment: I think $t$ could fail to have a constant term if the linear term of $t$ is also $0$.

Comment: Joe, constant terms don't affect the question, since they're fixed and $\sigma$ is a continuous homomorphism.  Keep in mind that $\sigma$ is defined by $\sigma(\tau):=\tau(u)$ for any $\tau\in\mathbb{F}_3[[T]]$, where $u:=c_1 T + f(T)$.  Crucially, $\sigma$ evaluates an arbitrary power series at a power series with no constant term, not the other way around.  So $\tau$ is fixed if and only if $\tau(u)=\tau$, and your argument says that if $\tau'(0)\ne 0$ then we obtain $u=T$ by subtracting $\tau(0)$ from both sides and then composing on the left with the inverse of $\tau-\tau(0)$.  But (cont.)

Comment: this only shows that no fixed points have a nonzero coefficient of $T$, not that there are no fixed points outside $\mathbb{F}_3$.

Comment: @Julian and Mike: Good point. I guess all that I eliminated was $t$'s of the form $T+h.o.t$. But maybe that's a start. My student, Matt Gardener-Spencer, looked at the action of the Nottingham group on the set of power series that look like $T^p+h.o.t.$. And someone else (I forget who at the moment) has done further work on that. Which might or might not be relevant. In any case, I thought the OP should know that papers on the Nottingham group might be helpful.

Comment: @MichaelZieve: I just edited my answer to include a link to Matt's thesis. He was mostly concerned with the conjugation action, but did prove a few things about the left and right actions. I'm not sure how much is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Let’s call $K=k((T))$, where $k$ is a field of characteristic $p>0$. Suppose $\Gamma$ is any finite subgroup of the group of $k$-automorphisms of $K$, any one such necessarily sending $T$ to $u(T)=\sum_1^\infty a_iT^i$, and thereby sending a general element of $K$, say $g(T)=\sum_?^\infty b_iT^i$, to $g\circ u=\sum_?^\infty b_iu^i$. Then if $|\Gamma|=n$, of course its fixed field $E\subset K$ has $[K\colon E]=n$. The extension will always be totally ramified, and with a nice generator equal to the norm of $T$, that is, $\prod_{\gamma\in\Gamma}\gamma(T)$. If we call this series $S$, then $E=k((S))$. Now if $u$ is a torsion element of Nottingham, then the group $\langle u\rangle$ is just such a $\Gamma$ as above, and we get a whole lot of fixed elements under right composition by $u$, all of them power series (or Laurent series, if you wish) in $S$.

Comment: Just to be clear: this answer is an augmentation of item (2) from my answer, namely, that if $\sigma$ has finite order then it has fixed points outside $\mathbf{F}_3$.  What is new here is the fact that the fixed point described in my answer generates all fixed points, in the sense that every fixed point is a formal power series in "my" fixed point.  On the other hand, this answer doesn't address infinite-order $\sigma$'s.